# What are the factors to take in consideration to improve server performance in AWS?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a server architecture on Amazon AWS like this: 
One EC2 instance with m1.large config and 
one RDS instance with db.m3.medium config. 
The EC2 contains an API that manages the requests, takes data from RDS database and returns it to the user.

I've done some performance testing using jmeter and I saw that sending 500 requests/second the servers maximum response time is at 10 seconds/request, minimum is 130 miliseconds and average about 4 seconds.
The metrics in AWS shows that EC2 processor is used only at 4%, the RDS proceessor is used at 20%. Unfortunately in EC2 AWS does not provide memory monitorisation, but in RDS the free available memory never drops under 2.6 Gb.

So having this results in 500 req/second why the response time is so big, if the servers are not working at full capacity? Is something else that I'm missing?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitoring, profiling, testing and incremental improvements is the way to go, let me share some resources for that:

To have memory monitoring, you can install the Cloudwatch Monitring Scripts for EC2. That can add memory, disk and swap monitoring as custom metrics.

see :http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html

For the profiling tools there is a lot. If you are running linux, Brendan Gregg's talk and book are a very good introduction to them:

see: http://www.joyent.com/blog/linux-performance-analysis-and-tools-brendan-gregg-s-talk-at-scale-11x

Also, note that different instance types can have very different network IO performance, try running your test comparing different instance types. In specific, check the  C3, R3 e I2 families, that support SR-IOV.

see: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/